# How to determine when a ProgressBar is over?

Tags: android, events, android-progressbar

I have a `ProgressBar` that is running for 10 seconds. I would like my app to display an `AlertDialog` when the progress bar is over. **How to do it**?

Doing a `while` cycle with `sleep()` doesn't work for me. Maybe I'm using it in a bad way?

```
while (progressBar.getProgress() != progressBar.getMax()) {
    sleep(1000);
}
// My AlertDialog will be displayed here
```

If there is a **quick and dirty** way to do this, I would prefer it. The app I'm programming is rather small.

Answer (score 1):

Its your program who sets the progress for a progressBar based on the progress of a task and you know when your task is over. Then you can dismiss the progressBar to close it. When you are closing the progressBar, you can show the alter dialog.

Take a look into this example - https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-progress-bar-example/. Just show your alert dialog after the following statement.

```
// close the progress bar dialog  
progressBar.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

use Handler.. while or sleep will freeze other process.

```
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        },10000);
```